# AVI video upside down

Tags: export, animation

Whenever I try to export a video in .avi format I am always getting a video upside down. Does anybody else get the same thing? I am running Mathematica 10.3.1 on an Ubuntu 12.04.5 machine. To check this behaviour simply go to wolfram documentation type ref/format/AVI and try to export the first example "traffic.avi".

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  I'm using version 10.3.1 on Linux, and when I do that example (which can be evaluated via `Get["http://pastebin.com/raw/ELc5K6y4"]` ), I get [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9vd5dkbv8favyg/traffic.avi?dl=1) as the result

Comment: @Jason B. Since the link that you sent me is also playing upside down I found out that the default player Totem Movie Player 3.0.1, as well as Dragon Player and SMPlayer, turn the picture upside down. On the contrary, in VLC media player and Kaffeine the video plays with the correct orientation.

Comment: do you get the same problem is you do something like `Export["test.avi", Table[Plot[ a x, ,{x,-2, 2}], {a, 1,20}]`?  Also, I don't get an upside down video from the default video player, which I think is Totem but is just called Videos.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is OS/system-related and not pertaining to *Mathematica*.